# Botkit custom middleware triggered multiple times for one message

Tags: node.js, express, botkit, slack-bot, botkit-middleware

I am trying to add custom middleware to detect the intent of user message in slackbot, but the middleware is triggered multiple times (usually 4 ~ 5 times) for one message.

I am sharing my controller and middleware what I am using.

This is my middleware:

```
import { SlackBotWorker } from "botbuilder-adapter-slack";
import { BotkitMessage } from "botkit";
import { NextFunction, Response } from "express";
import { logger } from "src/app";
import { chatCompletion } from "src/clients/openai/chat-completion";
import { OPEN_AI_INTENT_DETECTION_MESSAGE } from "./system-messages";

// Detect the intent from users' message and added intent to message object of botkit using this middleware
export const openAIIntentDetectionMiddleware = async (bot: SlackBotWorker, message: BotkitMessage, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const userMessage = message.text ?? '';

        if (userMessage !== '') {
            const response = await chatCompletion({ messages: [{ role: 'system', content: OPEN_AI_INTENT_DETECTION_MESSAGE }, { role: 'user', content: userMessage }] });

            const analyzedData = response ? JSON.parse(response) : { intent: 'default-fallback-intent', info: null };

            logger.debug('Open AI intent detection response:', { analyzedData });

            message.intent = analyzedData.intent;
            message.info = analyzedData.info;
            message.gptMessage = analyzedData.message;

        } else {
            message.intent = 'default-fallback-intent';
            message.info = null;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors here, such as API request failures.
        logger.error('Open AI intent detection failed:', { error })
    }

    next();
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
import { SlackAdapter } from 'botbuilder-adapter-slack';
import { Botkit } from 'botkit';
import { SLACK_WEBHOOK } from '../../constants';
import { logger } from '../../app';

import { openAIIntentDetectionMiddleware } from './middleware/openai-intent-detection.middleware';

export const initSlackController = (adapter: SlackAdapter): Botkit => {
  const controller = new Botkit({
    dialogStateProperty: `botbuilder-adapter-slack`,
    adapter,
    webhook_uri: SLACK_WEBHOOK,
    webserver: server,
    storage,
    // ...other options
  });

  controller.middleware.receive.use(openAIIntentDetectionMiddleware);

  controller.ready(async () => {
    // ... my controllers

    logger.info(`Slackbot Modules Loaded!`);
  });

  return controller;
};
```